Equivalence of two different forms of the operator norm of the Hessian?
I am currently reading a paper that considers the Hessian of a neural network with two parameter matrices, $\mathbf{A}\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ and $\mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{T \times N}.$
They proceed to upper bound the maximum eigenvalue by upper bounding $\max_{||v||=1}\mathbf{v}^T \big(\nabla^2 F \big) \mathbf{v},$ where $v = concat(\mathbf{p_1},...,\mathbf{p_T},\mathbf{q_1},...\mathbf{q_d}),$ and $\mathbf{p_i},\mathbf{q_i} \in \mathbb{R}^d.$
At this point, the authors claim that this can be essentially broken down into three terms corresponding to the three unique block matrices within the Hessian. Due to the particular definition of the Hessian in question, we happen to know that the upper left sub-hessian is all zeros, i.e. $\nabla^2_{AA}= \mathbb{0}_{TN \times TN}.$ So they say we can write the norm as a sum over contributions from each of the two non-zero blocks of the hessian (one of which is just its own transpose, so we count it twice):
$$2\sum_{t=1}^T \sum_{i=1}^N \mathbf{p_t}^T \Big(\nabla_B\big(\big[\nabla_A F\big]_{ti}\big)\Big) F \mathbf{q_i}+\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N \mathbf{q_i}^T \Big(\nabla_B\big(\big[ \nabla_B F\big]_{ij}\big)\Big) \mathbf{q_j}$$
At first glance, this made sense to me. we are taking the gradient of F with respect to A, looking at a specific element of that, $[\nabla_A F]_{ti},$ and then taking the gradient of that with respect to $B$. By staking these together properly, this gives us the block of the hessian $\nabla^2_{BA} \in \mathbb{R}^{TN\times N^2}.$ We then multiply with the corresponding segments of the global eigenvector, i.e. the $\mathbf{p_i}$ and $\mathbf{q_i}$ in the first sum. The dimensions of $\nabla_B\big(\big[\nabla_A F\big]_{ti}\big)$ is indeed $N \times N$, and the dimensions of $\nabla_B\big[ \nabla_B F\big]_{ij}$ is indeed also $N \times N$, which matches the dimensions of each of the left and right multiplying vectors, $p_t, q_i.$
But on closer inspection, I am confused how this makes any sense at all. This structure would imply that each pair of eigenvector segments $p_t,q_i$ corresponds to a a $d\times d$ matrix representing $\big[\nabla_A F\big]_{ti}.$ But this is not what understood Hessians to look like. I thought each row of the Hessian would correspond to the second derivative of a particular element of the gradient. So the gradients with respect to a fixed gradient element should be grouped into rows, not $N \times N$ matrices. One immediate contradiction that shows up in the above is that, if you take this nested structure of the hessian seriously, it would actually imply that the upper left derivative is not even square: it would be a $T\times N$ tiling of $T\times N$ gradients, forming a $T^2 \times N^2$ block, not a $TN \times TN$ one.
It seems that the fact that the nonzero blocks of the hessian are the right size is merely a coincidence, due to the fact that the matrices involved are $N \times N$ and $T \times N$. But if A was actually $T\times M$, this structure would imply that $\nabla^2_{BA}\in \mathbb{R}^{TN\times MN},$ which would leave a $MN \times MN$ hole for the bottom left block, which should have $\nabla^2_{BB} F \in \mathbb{R}^{ N^2\times N^2}$ in it!
So my question is -- how do they justify using this form of the calculation of the hessian's max eigenvalue? This approach only seems to work out nicely because the top left matrix is all zeros, and so we can hand waive away the incompatibility issue, while hiding it for the remaining matrices because A and B happen to be share all dimensions except one dimension in one matrix. Furthermore, how would we have dealt with it if the upper left block of the hessian was non-zero? If that matrix is indeed $T^2\times N^2$ as this nested formatting would suggest, then what segments of the original eigenvector are we using to left and right multiply each of the $T\times N$ gradient matrices within this block? There isn't even a $T-vector$ defined above as one of the segments of the eigenvector.
Or is there some kind of equivalence I'm missing that makes some kind of approach like this legal?
Any help is appreciated.
Thank you,
Paul
